Sending a message from telegram bot to telegram mini app
I've implemented some logic in javascript in my telegram mini app (TMA). My plan was for an event to register with the TMA, and it would make an HTTP call.
Is there a way to send messages from my telegram bot to the TMA so that the javascript logic would run? i.e. a user clicking a button would trigger the event
